# Map list of tuples into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I've got a list of tuples extracted from a table in a DB which looks like (*key* , *foreignkey* , *value*).  There is a many to one relationship between the key and foreignkeys and I'd like to convert it into a dict indexed by the foreignkey containing the sum of all values with that foreignkey, i.e. { *foreignkey* , *sumof(* value *)* }.  I wrote something that's rather verbose:

```
myDict = {}
for item in myTupleList:
    if item[1] in myDict:
        myDict [ item[1] ] += item[2]
    else:
        myDict [ item[1] ] = item[2]
```

but after seeing [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974678/how-to-create-single-python-dict-from-a-list-of-dicts-by-summing-values-with-comm) answer or [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261655/converting-a-list-of-tuples-into-a-dict-in-python) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233546/python-converting-list-of-tuples-into-a-dictionary) there's got to be a more concise way of expressing what I'd like to do.  And if this is a repeat, I missed it and will remove the question if you can provide the link.

Comment: Maybe off topic, but I'll ask...  Why isn't this done at the level of the DB? That's the kind of thing DBMSes are good at...

Comment: It's actually not a DB but accessed through an interface which treats it like a DB.  It's just a bunch of flat files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming all your values are `int`s, you could use a `defaultdict` to make this easier:

```
from collections import defaultdict

myDict = defaultdict(int)

for item in myTupleList:
    myDict[item[1]] += item[2]
```

`defaultdict` is like a dictionary, except if you try to get a key that isn't there it fills in the value returned by the callable - in this case, `int`, which returns 0 when called with no arguments.

UPDATE: Thanks to [@gnibbler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210581/map-list-of-tuples-into-a-dictionary-python/2210697#2210697) for reminding me, but tuples can be unpacked in a for loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict

myDict = defaultdict(int)

for _, key, val in myTupleList:
    myDict[key] += val
```

Here, the 3-item tuple gets unpacked into the variables `_`, `key`, and `val`. `_` is a common placeholder name in Python, used to indicate that the value isn't really important. Using this, we can avoid the hairy `item[1]` and `item[2]` indexing. We can't rely on this if the tuples in `myTupleList` aren't all the same size, but I bet they are.

(We also avoid the situation of someone looking at the code and thinking it's broken because the writer thought arrays were 1-indexed, which is what I thought when I first read the code. I wasn't alleviated of this until I read the question. In the above loop, however, it's obvious that `myTupleList` is a tuple of three elements, and we just don't need the first one.)

Comment: `myDict = reduce(lambda d, t: (d[t[1]] += t[2], d)[1], myTupleList, defaultdict(int))` - You know, everybody should use reduce!  *big grin*

Comment: Omnifarious, can you post that as an answer and explain it?  That looks very interesting.  I'm looking for anything that can teach me something new, especially a functionally flavored answer.

Comment: @wheaties, alright, since you asked.  *laugh*  I prefer Chris' solution much more though.  In this case `reduce` obscures.  And my solution is slightly wrong anyway, but I'll post the correct version.

Answer (score 5):

```
from collections import defaultdict

myDict = defaultdict(int)

for _, key, value in myTupleList:
    myDict[key] += value
```

Comment: There's three values in the tuple list, the first one just isn't used. But the simple fix is to put `_, ` before `key`, so +1.

Comment: This won't work because `myTupleList` is a three-element tuple.  You'll get `ValueError: too many values to unpack`.

Comment: @Chris Lutz, I wouldn't have minded if you had fixed it ... :)

Comment: @gnibbler - Some people get a bit uppidy if people edit their answers, but thanks.

Comment: I think this one is likely a little more efficient than Chris' original version.

Comment: I like this answer a lot too.  Very succinct.  Very clear on the meaning.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my (tongue in cheek) answer:

```
myDict = reduce(lambda d, t: (d.__setitem__(t[1], d.get(t[1], 0) + t[2]), d)[1], myTupleList, {})
```

It is ugly and bad, but here is how it works.

The first argument to reduce (because it isn't clear there) is `lambda d, t: (d.__setitem__(t[1], d.get(t[1], 0) + t[2]), d)[1]`.  I will talk about this later, but for now, I'll just call it `joe` (no offense to any people named Joe intended).  The reduce function basically works like this:

```
 joe(joe(joe({}, myTupleList[0]), myTupleList[1]), myTupleList[2])
```

And that's for a three element list.  As you can see, it basically uses its first argument to sort of accumulate each result into the final answer.  In this case, the final answer is the dictionary you wanted.

Now for `joe` itself.  Here is `joe` as a `def`:

```
def joe(myDict, tupleItem):
   myDict[tupleItem[1]] = myDict.get(tupleItem[1], 0) + tupleItem[2]
   return myDict
```

Unfortunately, no form of `=` or `return` is allowed in a Python `lambda` so that has to be gotten around.  I get around the lack of `=` by calling the `dict`s `__setitem__` function directly.  I get around the lack of return in by creating a tuple with the return value of `__setitem__` and the dictionary and then return the tuple element containing the dictionary.  I will slowly alter `joe` so you can see how I accomplished this.

First, remove the `=`:

```
def joe(myDict, tupleItem):
   # Using __setitem__ to avoid using '='
   myDict.__setitem__(tupleItem[1], myDict.get(tupleItem[1], 0) + tupleItem[2])
   return myDict
```

Next, make the entire expression evaluate to the value we want to return:

```
def joe(myDict, tupleItem):
   return (myDict.__setitem__(tupleItem[1], myDict.get(tupleItem[1], 0) + tupleItem[2]),
           myDict)[1]
```

I have run across this use-case for `reduce` and `dict` many times in my Python programming.  In my opinion, `dict` could use a member function `reduceto(keyfunc, reduce_func, iterable, default_val=None)`.  `keyfunc` would take the current value from the iterable and return the key.  `reduce_func` would take the existing value in the dictionary and the value from the iterable and return the new value for the dictionary.  `default_val` would be what was passed into `reduce_func` if the dictionary was missing a key.  The return value should be the dictionary itself so you could do things like:

```
myDict = dict().reduceto(lambda t: t[1], lambda o, t: o + t, myTupleList, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting it.  That is ugly and indecipherable but at least it's educational.  I'm so fond of list comprehensions that I was hoping there might be some sort of dictionary comprehension I could utilize.  I've gone with his answer.  It is as concise as you could get.

Comment: @wheaties, newer versions of Python (though I'm not sure how new they have to be) do have dictionary comprehensions.  I'm not positive you could make them work for you here in the manner you would like.  I did update my answer to add a nice function that could be added to the `dict` interface that would make situations like this one much easier to handle.

Comment: python 3 has dict comprehensions http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

Comment: @Corey Goldberg, thanks, I thought it might be a Py3k thing.  And, as I suspected, they do not help you solve this problem efficiently.  Concisely perhaps, but not efficiently because there's no good way to collect the results by dictionary key.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly readable but it should work:

```
fks = dict([ (v[1], True) for v in myTupleList ]).keys()
myDict = dict([ (fk, sum([ v[2] for v in myTupleList if v[1] == fk ])) for fk in fks ])
```

The first line finds all unique foreign keys. The second line builds your dictionary by first constructing a list of (fk, sum(all values for this fk))-pairs and turning that into a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and see if that does all the mapping you need and perhaps more