# Convert a list of dictionaries to a dictionary using dict constructor

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the code snippet below that I want to get a dictionary from a list of dictionaries but getting global name item not found error. Wondering if it is possible to enumerate like below

```
l = [{1:{'item1':'value1'}},{2:{'item2':'value2'}}]
dic = dict(((k,v)) for k,v in item.items() for item in l) 
print dic
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `for ... in ...` clauses backwards.  They should go in the same order as if they were normal for-loops:

```
>>> l = [{1:{'item1':'value1'}},{2:{'item2':'value2'}}]
>>> dic = dict(((k,v)) for item in l for k,v in item.items())
>>> dic
{1: {'item1': 'value1'}, 2: {'item2': 'value2'}}
>>>
```

Also, I would like to point out that in Python 2.6+, you can use a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) for this:

```
>>> l = [{1:{'item1':'value1'}},{2:{'item2':'value2'}}]
>>> dic = {k:v for item in l for k,v in item.items()}
>>> dic
{1: {'item1': 'value1'}, 2: {'item2': 'value2'}}
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ordering of the statements is wrong. Think of it in the way that you would order it in a normal loop. So, `for item in l` comes first and then `for k, v in item.items()`.

```
>>> dic = dict(((k,v)) for item in l for k,v in item.items())
>>> dic
{1: {'item1': 'value1'}, 2: {'item2': 'value2'}}
```

Now, the comprehension becomes

```
for item in l:
    for k, v in item.items():
        # Do Something
```

instead of

```
for k, v in item.items():
    for item in l:
        # Do Something
```

which is an error.

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension for's are interpreted just like a normal for loop(which actually is somewhat counter intuitive) so what you have is

```
for k,v in item.items():
   for item in mylist:
       k,v
```

surely you can see the problem with that

Answer (score 0):

first refer to ques [How to create single Python dict from a list of dicts by summing values with common keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974678/how-to-create-single-python-dict-from-a-list-of-dicts-by-summing-values-with-com)

It will help you to analyse your problem.....now thhink of normal loops...

```
>>> dic = dict(((k,v)) for item in l for k,v in item.items())
>>> dic
{1: {'item1': 'value1'}, 2: {'item2': 'value2'}}
```

then handled as....

```
for item in l:
    for k, v in item.items():
```